# SharePoint online 2019 Communication site / tabs

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2019

I am a Librarian tasked with building a SharePoint site for our college staff and students. The site is SharePoint online 2019 and is a Communication site.

Within a site page l need to insert tabs (four) and within each one add web parts such as Quick Links or images. The tabs will contain subject guide resources which we cannot accommodate in a site page as  it wouid result in too much scrolling.

I am a novice with minimal coding experience. Can you tell me if this is possible with the type of site l am working with and the layout l am attempting to produce? Also, how would l actually do it?

Thanks for any input offered.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to add tabs in classic or modern pages, custom code is required since SharePoint pages don’t support adding tabs in OOB solutions.

Second, communication site doesn’t support Content Editor web part or Script Editor web part for wiki pages. So, using wiki pages in communication site to create tabs is not possible, which leaves you with no other options than to customize modern site pages.

Please see the references below.

Modern pages:

How to customize modern pages: [Customizing "modern" site pages.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages)

An Example: [SharePoint List Formatting Tabs.](https://www.sharepointsiren.com/2019/09/sharepoint-list-formatting-tabs/)

Classic pages:

An Example: [How to: Use tabs to easily display SharePoint views.](https://www.sharepointsapiens.com/blog/how-to-use-tabs-to-easily-display-sharepoint-views/)

Comment: Many thanks for your help with the links. I will take a look.